# Check current Brightness android

Tags: java, android, togglebutton, brightness

I can't make working my code.. I want check the current brightness and if is in authomatic my `ToggleButton` will be checked else not. I explain; This is what i'm trying to do to check the brightness:

```
public static final int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC = 1;
---
---


int curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), 
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,-1);

        //
        if (curBrightnessValue == 1){
            autoBrightToggle.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            autoBrightToggle.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

of course then there is the toggle:

```
autoBrightToggle = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.luminosita);
        autoBrightToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (autoBrightToggle.isChecked()) {
                    setAutoBrightness(true);
                } else {
                    setAutoBrightness(false);
                }
            }
        });
---
---
---
void setAutoBrightness(boolean value) {
        if (value) {
            Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
        } else {
            Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
        }
    }
```

But doesn't works. it crash with this logCat

```
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136): Process: com.dd.androreboot, PID: 15136
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at com.dd.androreboot.devicecontrolfragment.onCreateView(devicecontrolfragment.java:78)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-09 22:03:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(15136):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's line 78 in devicecontrolfragment.java?

Comment: this: `autoBrightToggle.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: then it means autoBrightToggle is null. but you already know that, obviously. you also probably already checked that luminosita is present in the hierarchy of `v`, where v probably comes from an xml layout.

Comment: I can't understand.. I mean, seems correct my idea.. or not? Is there any other way to do that? Check the brightness mode.. If auto then check the toggle else not... Do you know how could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

David please provide more information or verify your onCreateView() in devicecontrolfragment.java for null values, that's what is causing a problem here. (devicecontrolfragment.java: line 78)
As a side note, also make sure you have relevant permissions for this action.

Comment: the permissions are ok. At line 78 the is: `autoBrightToggle.setEnabled(false);`..i don't know

Comment: I sugggest the following: Before you try to make any changes in the system, verify your UI is working correctly. Comment the system methods calls and verify you didn't make any UI mistakes. Next try to verify (with logs or whatever) that you get the information you need from the system as you expect in your code.